# React native shows incorrect element measures

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just want to get the measurements of this element, unreal.

The element

```
<View style={styles.top}>
    <Animated.View
        style={[styles.textWrapper]}>
        <Text
            onLayout={(event) => {
                this.layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
            }}
            style={[styles.text]}>Hola</Text>
    </Animated.View>
</View>
```

Styles :

```
top: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
},
textWrapper: {
    justifyContent: "center",
},
text: {
    position: 'absolute',
    fontSize: 60
}
```

And then I'm logging the element's measures inside the `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
    const {x, y, height, width} = this.layout;
    console.log('x, y, height, width', x, y, height, width);


    })
```

/// 0 , -35.23232323 , 75.3434234234 ,32.22323434
    }

[Here's the snack](https://snack.expo.io/By7bLFenM)

Even though visually, the element is somewhere in the center of the screen, you can see that the numbers are totally wrong.

How can `y` even be negative when I can see the element is on the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your `Text` element, you used the `position: "absolute"` style prop, but didn't provide `left` or `top` or `bottom` or `right` prop.
If you add `left:0, top:0` style props to your `Text` element, then the result of `x` and `y` will be `0` instead of a negative number:

```
text: {
    position: 'absolute',
    fontSize: 60,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
}
```

The last question:

> How can y even be negative when I can see the element is on the
>   screen?

We can see it just because there is no other opaque element that covers the element.